# Nest Thermostat structure: Add a new data field

Tags: nest-api

I am developing a thermostat based application. I am in a process to define set of parameters for the sensor. Nest thermostat API supports most of the sensor
parameters.
**Question**: Is it possible to add a custom parameter in Device structure, is Nest
thinking to add such feature in future?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such provision in Nest. This is answered here.
https://nestdevelopers.io/t/nest-thermostat-structure-add-new-data-field/878